# Add a transparent UITableViewCell at the end of the Groupedtableview with no bordercolor

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a grouped `UITableView`. It has 7 rows. I wanted  a transparent cell at the end so that I can give a scroll buffer at the end of the tableView. I tried to add a transparent cell at the end of the tableView but as it is grouped tableView the border color appears. I just need empty space at the end of the tableView. Any efficient way of doing it will be helpful.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this comment: "I wanted a transparent cell at the end so that I can give a scroll buffer at the end of the tableView." What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My tableview's scroll height should be greater than the sum of heights of all the cell. So, when i reach the last row of my tableview, i need to see the last row at the top with empty space at the bottom..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why don't you try setting the [`contentInset`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentInset) that `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`?

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0);
```

Positive bottom inset should add the buffer you need. `20.0` might not be a big inset so adjust as you need.

Alternatively, you can also try setting the [`tableFooterView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableFooterView) property of `UITableView`.

Comment: i had set the bottom inset.. works like a charm. My table view had som text boxes.. Adding the inset at the bottom made the text box disappear off the screen.. Had to register to the keyboard notifications n then set the inset accordingly..

Comment: really! this is a charm! like apple for their simple solutions :)